# server side pagination in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring

I am trying to implement server side pagination in Angular JS .I have created   my server response consisting of `results` and a variable called `isMoreResults` . When `isMoreResults` is true I can safely assume that it has more results to be displayed . Now how can I go about creating a pagination on angular Js side ,such that I can display `PREVIOUS` and `NEXT` . when user clicks on next I can call the server to fetch next response .Any leads on how can I implement and what is the correct format to implement pagination ? I have went through many sites and majoritily I could see client side validation .should I also switch to client side validation ?

Comment: use filter `limit` to limit the data to display + Display next button is `isMoreResults` is true + Click on next button will call server. Try something and come back when you have errors

Comment: For server side we need help from back-end also. Our side create directive for pagination or else 3rd party module. Pagination first we need total count , records per page from this we can get how many pages to show. While click next API call will go with skip rows(10, 20) and other parameter also as per your need.

Comment: I don't want the user to go directly to third page . I would love to make him go from page 1 , next -> page 2 . Still do I need to configure my API to return total results etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
 angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('app').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.currentPage = 1;
     $scope.limit= 10;


      $scope.tracks = [];
      getData();


      function getData() {
        $http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=iron+&offset="+($scope.currentPage-1)*$scope.limit+"&limit=20&type=artist")
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.totalItems = response.data.artists.total
            angular.copy(response.data.artists.items, $scope.tracks)


          });
      }

    //get another portions of data on page changed
      $scope.pageChanged = function() {
        getData();
      };


    });
```

in html

```
   <div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Sample Server Pagination</h4>

    <uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="100"></uib-pagination>          
  </div>
```

Comment: Now , how can I traverse back . If I am on second page , how can I come back to first page

Comment: uib-pagination handles that. when you click on first page link you'll get $scope.currentPage=1.

Answer (score 0):

Usually do this for pagination:

1 - Create an API that takes how many `SKIP` and how many `TAKE` .. somehting like:

```
http://www.test.com/api/Users?skip=0&take=10
```

Then:

2 - in Angular install this plugin: (maybe with bower or npm)

```
https://github.com/brantwills/Angular-Paging
```

3 - in your HTML something like:

```
 <paging page="currentPage" 
                page-size="pageSize" 
                total="total"
                paging-action="DoPaging(page, pageSize, total)">

        </paging>
```

4 - In your Controller:

```
/**
 * MainCtrl - controller
 */
"use strict";
angular
    .module('demo')
    .controller('UsersCtrl', [
        "$scope",
        "User",

        "$state",
        "$timeout",
        function (
            $scope,
            User,            
            $state,
            $timeout) {

            var vm = this;

            // Binded Functions


            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.pageSize = 10;

            $scope.DoPaging = _doPaging;
```

// Page Load
                init();

```
            /////////////////////////////////
            // PRIVATE FUNCTION
            ////////////////////////////////

            //Page Load
            function init() {

                $scope.promUsers = User.GetUsers(0, 10).$promise.then(function (resp) {
                    vm.users = resp;
```

$scope.total = resp[0].total //<-- put in your Back End Entities a field where you store how many record you have on your DB (all)
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }

```
            function _doPaging(text, page, pageSize, total) {
                var skip = pageSize * (page -1);

                User.GetUsers(skip, pageSize).$promise.then(function(resp){
                    vm.users = resp;
                    $scope.total = resp[0].total 
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }



            ////////////////////////////////


        }]);
```

5 - In your service:

```
"use strict";

angular
    .module("demo")
    .factory("User", [
        "$resource",
        "$q",

        "enviroment",
        "$timeout",
        function (
            $resource,
            $q,

            enviroment,
            $timeout) {


            // Private Filed
            var _serviceBase = "api/User/";


            // Private Method

            //skip and take in query string
            var resource = $resource(enviroment.apiUrl + _serviceBase, { skip: '@skip', take: '@take' }, {
                query: { method: "GET", isArray: true },
                create: { method: "POST", isArray: false },
                update: { method: "PUT", isArray: false }
            });



            // Public Method
            return {
                GetUsers: function (skip, take) {
                    return resource.query({ skip: skip, take: take });
                }

            };
        }]);
```